# Session Attributes in Google Actions

Tags: actions-on-google

I just started exploring developing an action using google actions few days back. Right now I am facing a problem.

What actually I want is that I want to save the information (in the session as attributes) from what user speaks/utters and use that attributes anytime the skill is active.

I came to know about the contexts but the problem with contexts is that it has a lifespan while what I want is to hold the information throughout the session (when the action is started till the action is ended.)

Any help?
Thanks-in-advance.

Answer (score 0):

First - contexts are a perfectly good solution to this problem. You can set the context to have a long lifespan (say, 99) and it will be valid for 99 exchanges between your agent and the user.

You can also set an attribute in the `data` object if you're using the Actions-on-Google library. (Google just turns this into a context with a long lifespan and manages it for you.)

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47538390/1405634 for more details on both of these.