# How to perform Firebase Authentication using Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I was wondering if anybody has tried to implement a Telegram chatbot that requires the user to login.

I have an intent in dialogflow that requests the user's login ID (their email) and password, but I have no idea how to code that in the fulfillment.

If anybody has some sample codes to show me, that will be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I have attempted this and succeeded. However, it is quite a headache to set up. Basically, you need to use Dialogflow fulfillment to call a firebase function. There, you need to use Firebase Auth's ability to sign in with a custom token. (You might want to consider some form of encryption at this point). Then you send the token back to dialogflow. Now you have to store that token in [one of many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47538390/9462397). Once again, you will definitely want to encrypt the token. Each time you send a message then, you send along the token to your function, which will (using Promises) either accept it if the token is correct or reject it if it is not.

See [this code](https://github.com/malikasinger1/Quiz-Assistant/blob/master/functions/) which shows how to use custom token auth with dialogflow. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey A.S.H thanks so much for the information. You were using Firebase Admin SDK right? For the real-time database, you may only use the Admin SDK?

Comment: Yes, I was using the admin sdk in my Firebase functions. Note that my Firebase functions weren't the ones right there in Dialogflow, but a full node.js project linked to my Firebase app